# How can I get the id of the record with the email, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a test MySQL with a field which is unique as e-mailadres. Now I want to check before adding a record if the email already exists. I have the following code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";
$servername = "localhost";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//test met voorbeeld
$emailtest="adres@me.com ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM salonkeuze WHERE emailadres='$emailtest' ";
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
$id = $row['voorkeur_id'];
Echo $id;
?>
```

When I use an email address which is in de table. I don’t get any output. What do I wrong?

Comment: Solved, I did change to object orientated. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Here `$emailtest="adres@me.com ";` you can extra space after `com`, try to remove it -> `$emailtest="adres@me.com";`

Comment: That was a mistype. With of without the space the same result comes out: nothing....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you use wrong variable in this line:

```
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

Correct:

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

And it's optional, but it will be good, if you use **[trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** function for your **$email**. Because if your data comes from inputs and if $email have spaces, you can't show correct results:

```
$emailtest = "adres@me.com ";
$emailtest = trim($emailtest);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM salonkeuze WHERE emailadres='$emailtest' ";
```

Comment: Hi Malik, I tried your changes, $conn, how could I get that wrong.... but... it does not change the result. Strange?

Comment: @Pruus, can you share your database screenshot? Or what type error did you get? Please enable error_reporting() in your php file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I did add already an error catch. But I get no errors, only a blank screen. I checked all, table name, fields.

Comment: OMG, I saw it just now. Your mysqli connection is not procedural style, it's object oriented. So you must edit your last lines: `$data = $conn -> query($sql); $row = $data -> fetch_assoc();`. İf that doesn't help, then there's a problem. But I can no longer understand it without seeing the entire database and code.

Comment: I did change this. But no changes. Thanks for your sharp eye!

Comment: I have change te code, thanks for your tips. Below the code which works fine. Thanks

Comment: Solved! Thanks to You all! By changing it to procederal. Thanks!!!

Comment: I forgot to write at my last comment, if you use mysqli object oriented style, then you must use like this `$id = $row->voorkeur_id;` instead of `$id = $row['voorkeur_id'];`. OR you can use procedural style for all codes too. Yes, you already find a solution.